# Flushing a virtual address range

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cpu-cache

I am developing a Linux kernel module that interfaces with a hardware component accessing the DDR using DMA. (running on an arm SoC)

What the driver essentially does is allocate a buffer (w/ kmalloc), and write the physical (using virt_to_phys) address of the buffer to the underlying hardware

When reading the buffer, the old data seems to get read, which points to a cache problem (when inspecting the DDR directly, bypassing Linux, the new data is read).

I can't seem to understand how cache flushing / invalidation works.

What is the best approach?

Using kernel 3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. use coherent mapping that is allocate memory using dma_alloc_coherent
2. use streaming mapping that is map the buffer for dma using dma_map_single telling the kernel the DMA direction and unmap it after you finish

Comment: Thanks. Can I use either if the methods to allocate physically contiguous memory?

Comment: on dma_alloc_coherent you get a physically continuous memory buffer. If you use dma_map_single you need to pass it a continuos allocated buffer (allocated for example using kmalloc)